# How to to trigger a tag when clicking on a element with a certain class in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

In Tag Manager I need to trigger an event when I click an element with a certain class. The events don't always work. Sometimes it will fire correctly 10 times in a row when I click and sometimes it won't fire for 15 clicks.

I'm currently using:

- **Trigger type:** Click - All Elements
- **Trigger fires on:** Some Clicks
- **Conditions:** [ Click Element ] [ matches CSS selector ] [ .classname ]

To test I'm using a simple custom HTML tag:

```
console.log('clicked '+ Date.now())
```

Sometimes when I click I get the console log, but not always. It seems to be random. How to make it reliable?

Answer (score 0):

Update: the random behaviour was caused by the trigger not firing on child elements of the parent that was targeted by the classname. All children need to be included in the selector with .classname *